# NHibernate reference back - hasmany and reference to the same entity

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, reference, mapping

I have problem with situation like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        Bars = new List<Bar>();
        AddBar(new Bar(this));
    }

    public IList<Bar> Bars {get;private set;}

    public Bar LastBar {get;private set;}

    public void AddBar(Bar bar)
    {
        Bars.Add(bar);
        LastBar = bar;
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public Bar(Foo foo)
    {
        BelongsToFoo = foo;
    }

    public Foo BelongsToFoo {get;private set;}

    //...
}
```

When I do that:

```
var f = new Foo();
Repository.Save<Foo>(f); // -> exception - BelongsToFoo is null
```

When I remove updating LastBar

```
LastBar = bar;
```

and set as nullable everything works fine but LastBar is null, of course. I want to have last Bar properly assigned and saved.

How should I properly map this entities?

**Edit 1**
This happend only when creating new objects. When I update Foo and add new bars everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem and solution.

I use http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/04/29/nhibernate-ipreupdateeventlistener-amp-ipreinserteventlistener.aspx for tracking last date and user change info.

In my case NHibernate needs to do:

1. insert Foo
2. insert Bar
3. update Foo.LastBar (foreign key)

At.1. NHibernate invoke OnPreInsert but at.3. invoke OnPreUpdate on the same entity but persister loose informations about CreatedAt, CreatedBy properties.

I changed OnPreUpdate to copy this two values explicit from entity object.

PS
I know that exception is weird and not adequate to this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you map the list and the many-to-one reference to the same column and make the list inverse.

Remove the not-null constraint from the BelongsToFoo property. NH sometimes needs to store a record with null references and updates it later when the identities of the referenced objects are obtained. This happens more frequent when using the identity generator.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm doing this. :(

Comment: I'm always using HiLo and don't have not-null constraint on BelongsToFoo property. :(